# code works in jsfiddle but not browser using freeCodeCamp inline validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use this data validation code using JavaScript from the freeCodeCamp website to implement into my code, but when I test the code itself in vscode using a live browser, it doesn't work, but works well in jsfiddle. I'm not sure why it doesn't work well in a browser?

freeCodeCamp article i got it from:https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/form-validation-with-html5-and-javascript/

freeCodeCamp jsfiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/0tq3e49w/4/

Html code:

```
<form id="form">
  <label for="firstname"> First Name* </label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>

  <span role="alert" id="nameError" aria-hidden="true">
    Please enter First Name
  </span>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const firstNameField = document.getElementById("firstname");
  let valid = true;

  if (!firstNameField.value) {
    const nameError = document.getElementById("nameError");
    nameError.classList.add("visible");
    firstNameField.classList.add("invalid");
    nameError.setAttribute("aria-hidden", false);
    nameError.setAttribute("aria-invalid", true);
  }
  return valid;
}
```

CSS code:

```
#nameError {
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#nameError.visible {
  display: block;
}

input.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do form submission with the submit event on a form and not a click of a button. Just better practice.

Comment: You only set the return to true. You prevent every click if it is valid or not because you use  `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a condition if the field is invalid but you didn't add a condition if the field is valid to reset the invalid styles.

```js
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const firstNameField = document.getElementById("firstname");
  if (!firstNameField.value) {
    const nameError = document.getElementById("nameError");
    nameError.classList.add("visible");
    firstNameField.classList.add("invalid");
    nameError.setAttribute("aria-hidden", false);
    nameError.setAttribute("aria-invalid", true);
  } else {
    firstNameField.classList.remove("invalid");
    nameError.classList.remove("visible");
        nameError.setAttribute("aria-hidden", true);
    nameError.setAttribute("aria-invalid", false);
  }
}
```

```css
#nameError {
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#nameError.visible {
  display: block;
}

input.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="firstname"> First Name* </label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>

  <span role="alert" id="nameError" aria-hidden="true">
    Please enter First Name
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried copying and pasting that into the separate vscode files I have, but it still seems to not work on the live browser I have

Comment: Do you use external files for `js` and `css` or all on same file?

Comment: I used external files for the js and css

Comment: Make sure, you add the `script` tag at the bottom of the `body` tag, and the `link` tag in the `head` tag.

Comment: Ahh THANKS IT WORKS!! Sorry I'm a rookie at coding, so I didn't know that I was supposed to do that. But thank you!!  ╰(▔∀▔)╯

Comment: Never mind, have a good day.